# Coral Print House Magic & Windows 10

Tags: software-recommendation

I have an old version of Corel Print House Magic that will not work on Windows 10 - I would like to know if there is a inexpensive program similar to Print House that has the capabilities to ungroup clipart

Answer (score 0):

For simpler things you can use Serif Draw plus http://www.serif.com/free-graphic-design-software/

or Libre Office https://libreoffice.org/

Depending on the format of the clipart you could expliore thoose.

For more elaborated things Inkscape https://inkscape.org/ or the payed solutions like Corel Draw and Ilustrator.

Answer (score 0):

I have print house 4 on Windows 11. The program loaded ok, but would not run. I went to the program files (x86) on c drive, selected Coral, then Print House Magic, scrolled down to printhse application, right clicked to get into properties. In compatibility I set it to Windows 98. It now runs and I have rescued many old projects.